# Nginx Conf for multiple projects and locations

Tags: nginx

So I have 2 projects (made in Angular), for frontend and admin.

I want `location / {}` to serve frontend folder, and `location /admin {}` to serve admin folder.

Also, note that I don't want to add base href in admin project, like `--base-href=/admin/`

So what I have untill now is:

```
location {
    root /home/ubuntu/front/dist;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
}

location /admin {
    rewrite ^/admin/(.*) /$1 break;
    root /home/ubuntu/admin/dist;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ =404;
}
```

So I have 2 problems with this:

1. /admin is not being matched with regex, but /admin/ is.
2. Nginx is trying to look for files in folder dist/admin, therefore I get 404 page.

I tried adding/removing the end slash everywhere, and in most cases I am just getting redirected from /admin to / and getting served the frontend app.

I think I need to fix rewrite rule, and also somehow ignore starting "/admin" for each route, since the admin project doesn't have that prefix.

Comment: by using `root` in the admin location nginx will append the requested url to the root path leading to `/home/ubuntu/admin/dist/admin/…`. Have a look at alias instead. That way you should also be able to remove the rewrite which basically rewrites the request to the first location again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to avoid rewriting the second location to the first location and also to avoid appending the request url by using `alias` instead of `root`:

```
location / {
    root /home/ubuntu/front/dist;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
}

location /admin {
    alias /home/ubuntu/admin/dist;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ =404;
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with this solution, whenever I refresh the page, I get 404 nginx error.